# fullpage.js How to make external links with active section and active slides.?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Hello I'm making a mobile web with fullpage.js I'm triying to make an external link to a specific section/slide but its not working, after looking at why it is not working I discovered when you make an active slide or section, all external links to a section directs you to the active section and not the section/slide of the link.

This is an example of the code I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage',],

</script>
<body>
<div id="fullpage">

<div class="section" id="section0">content</div>

   <div class="slide" id="slide0">content</div>

 <div class="section active" id="section1">content</div>

   <div class="slide" id="slide0">content</div> 

 <div class="slide active" id="slide1">content</div> 

   <div class="slide" id="slide2">content</div> 

 <div class="section" id="section2">content</div>

</body>
```

With this code when I enter the first page, what I see is the Section1 in the slide3 thats my main page, because thats the design of the navigation.

And the url looks like this www.myweb.com/#secondPage/1

But I need to make an external link to the www.myweb.com/#thirdPage (section2)

When I made the link and click it, it always sends me to the active section/slide 
www.myweb.com/#secondPage/1 never to the url I want to link.

But when I clear the active sections the external links, it works fine to any section.  I think the problem is with the active sections/slides

How can I keep my main page #secondPage/1 (active) and make the external links to the areas I want?

Comment: Please edit the post and share your code so far.

Comment: Edited, feel free to help if u can.

Comment: It's beyond my expertise, but I have fixed English issues with it.  And I have upvoted it, now that the question is of a better quality.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in fullPage.js.
Please feel free to report it [in github](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues).